# String constant delimiters that don't banalize line feeds?

Tags: c#

in Python, I can do something like that to assign a string "WYSIWYG style". It will take into account my line feeds and all spaces and tabs. That proves to be useful in many circumstances.

python:

```
HTMLSnippet = """
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
""" 

print HTMLSnippet
```

the output of this would be :

```xml
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any such string tool in C# ? Or something to fulfill the same needs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

With verbatim strings, you can include multi line strings like e.g.

```
const string myString = @"
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Sounds like it should be a statement.

Comment: Is it not allowed to start posting and then add more text on a turn-by-turn basis? (I think) I saw that even Jon Skeet doing it this way.

Comment: It is allowed, but you really should start with a proper answer and at least say that you are going to add an example. A one liner that is a question simply looks like something that should be a comment (and you are lucky it didn't automatically convert to one).

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. Part of the [classic fastest-gun-in-the-west (FGITW) problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Sometimes it backfires, though, so it's not a foolproof strategy. But my comment was more a response to Oded's now-deleted +5 "this should be a comment", so don't read too much into it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx):

```
string HTMLSnippet = @"<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>";
```